# Consulta sobre corchetes en python

Tags: python

Teniendo en cuenta el siguiente código:

```
def recommend(username, users):

  nearest = computeNearestNeighbor(username, users)[0][1]
  recommendations = []
  neighborRatings = users[nearest]
  userRatings = users[username]

  for artist in neighborRatings:
     if not artist in userRatings:
        recommendations.append((artist,neighborRatings[artist]))

 return recommendations
```

El codigo de computeNearestNeighbor:

```
def computeNearestNeighbor(username,users):
  """creates a sorted list of users based on their distance to username""" 
  distances = []
  for user in users:
    if user!=username:
      distance = manhattan(users[user],users[username])
      distances.append((distance, user))
  # Sort based on the distance -- closest first
  distances.sort()
  return distances
```

Me podrían decir qué hacen los dos corchetes `[0][1]`, luego esta sentencia?

```
nearest = computeNearestNeighbor(username, users)
```

Comment: Se deduce que la función `computeNearestNeighbor()` retorna una lista (o tupla) y que esa lista tiene al menos un elemento, que es lo que se selecciona con el primer `[0]`. Se ve que ese primer elemento es a su vez otra lista (o tupla) que tiene al menos dos elementos, y el `[1]` que va luego selecciona el segundo elemento de la misma. Es decir, es lo mismo que `result = computeNearestNeighbor(username, users)`, seguido de `nearest = result[0][1]`

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Añado el código completo de la funcion computeNearestNeighbor(username, users)


def computeNearestNeighbor(username,users):
 """creates a sorted list of users based on their distance to
  username"""

 distances = []
 for user in users:
  if user!=username:
   distance = manhattan(users[user],users[username])
   distances.append((distance, user))

 # Sort based on the distance -- closest first
 distances.sort()
 return distances

Comment: Como habrás podido ver, en los comentarios no se puede insertar código adecuadamente. Se pierde todo el formato. Pero puedes editar la pregunta para añadirlo.

Comment: Lo acabo de implementar como lo mencionaste en la respuesta! Lo entendí! Muchas gracias @abulafia! Nunca había visto ese "truquito"!  Con respecto a los comentarios, no sabía que no se podía insertar código. Soy nuevo en esto :)